# Is there a 'value in time' concept in metrics, or how do I create one?

Tags: clojure, metrics, codahale-metrics

I am using `metrics-clojure` http://metrics-clojure.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ lists gauges, counters, meters, timers and histograms.

What I want is instead to report a number.
Very much like counter, but with a set! operation instead of just inc!/dec! or a meter that accepts a value.

One use case is processing batches of events. I can create a meter to watch the batches, but I would prefer to include the batch size such that the reporting end can use the correct units (so I can plot the number of events processed instead of the number of batches).

Another use case is wanting to produce a plot of some number that changes over time. Say again I was processing events, and I wanted to plot per event how many unique combinations of events I'd seen so far, how can I do this?

I can fake this a little bit with a gauge. I can create an atom, and have the gauge report the atom value, and set the atom value in the code... but I can't control when the gauge will report the value. So the value will only be plotted at points whenever the gauge happened to be queried, but I might want to record the values at more specific points (like the end of a batch, at intervals in a batch, or on every event).

And it seems convoluted.

Any suggestions?